# Openvpn client can only ping one of two interfaces in the same AWS Linux 2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, openvpn

I have an AWS Linux 2 instance, with two interfaces in different subnets, where I installed **Openvpn** using the **172.23.0.0/24** network. **Openvpn** is working and I can connect to it. However, from the remote client I can only ping the interface connected to the Internet and the **Openvpn** tunnel interface which has the **172.23.0.1** address. I can not ping the other interface with the **10.0.0.8** address. From the instance, I can ping all addresses. If I run tcpdump, I can see the packets arriving from the remote client, but the interface does not respond.

I have stoped source and destination check and I have also activated ip forwarding with `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and even tried `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp=1` and `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp_pvlan=1`. This is a brand new instance where the only thing installed is Openvpn. No firewall.

Can not figure this out and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Can you post the security group settings of both ENIs?

Comment: Thanks @jellycsc,  permit all traffic on both interfaces and accept all in both internal firewall.